# JavaScript - filter array of objects by content of primitive array in O(n)

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, time-complexity

I have the following array of objects:

```
[{
  itemType: 'bottle',
  itemId: '111'
}, {
  itemType: 'bottle',
  itemId: '222'
}, {
  itemType: 'bottle',
  itemId: '333'
}]
```

I'm trying to filter (time complexity of O(n)) it by a simple array like the following:

```
[ '111', '333' ]
```

So the final array of objects looks like this:

```
[{
  itemType: 'bottle',
  itemId: '222'
}]
```

I thought using `underscoreJS` but there's no builtin function to accomplish this in a simple manner. Any other options?

Comment: Iterate over the source array, use a set for the IDs to remove. This requires a different data structure for what to remove, but keeps you to a single iteration and it's still O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a linear complexity solution you must tradeoff some space complexity to be able to perform a single linear search through the array. What you can do is convert your array of matches into a set, reducing the id existence lookup from `O(ids.length)` to `O(1)` and thus reducing your total complexity from `O(arr.length*ids.length)` to `O(arr.length) + O(ids.length)`:

If you cannot tradeoff any space, your total complexity will be quadratic: `O(arr.length * ids.length)`.

ES6 solution `O(arr.length) + O(ids.length)`:

```js
const arr = [{itemType: 'bottle', itemId: '111'},{itemType: 'bottle', itemId: '222'},{itemType: 'bottle', itemId: '333'}];
const ids = ['111', '333'];

function filter(arr, ids) {
  const s = new Set(ids); // O(ids.length) to build the set and use O(ids.length) space
  return arr.filter(item => s.has(item.itemId)); // O(arr.length) to filter the array
}

console.log(filter(arr, ids));
```

ES5 solution `O(arr.length) + O(ids.length)`:

```js
var arr = [{itemType: 'bottle', itemId: '111'},{itemType: 'bottle', itemId: '222'},{itemType: 'bottle', itemId: '333'}];
var ids = ['111', '333'];

function filter(arr, ids) {
  // O(ids.length) to build the set and use O(ids.length) space
  var s = ids.reduce(function(s, id) {
    s[id] = true;
    return s;
  }, Object.create(null));

  // O(arr.length) to filter the array
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return s[item.itemId];
  });
}

console.log(filter(arr, ids));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that

```
var a = [{
    itemType: 'bottle',
    itemId: '111'
},
 {
    itemType: 'bottle',
    itemId: '222'
},
{
    itemType: 'bottle',
    itemId: '333'
}]
```

AND

```
var b = [ '111', '333' ]
```

So using underscore methods this can be simply done:

```
_.filter(a, function(ele) {
    return !_.contains(b, ele.itemId)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

By using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the blacklist we can remove duplicates and save lookup time.

```
const blacklist = new Set(['111', '333']);
const items = [
    {
        itemType : 'bottle',
        itemId   : '111'
    },
    {
        itemType : 'bottle',
        itemId   : '222'
    },
    {
        itemType : 'bottle',
        itemId   : '333'
    }
];

const filtered = items.filter((item) => {
    return !blacklist.has(item.itemId);
});
```

In the above code, `filtered` is an array of `items` objects whose `itemId` does not appear on the `blacklist`.